# View More/Less toggle is being pushed down off page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out what is causing my view more/less toggle to be pushed downward off screen in mobile view, only happens on main page, doesn't happen when I log in.

```
<div class="view-content-links mobile-hidden">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="view_more_link" class="view-content-link">View More</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="view_less_link" class="view-content-link">View Less</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
Y.use('jquery-ui',function(Y) {
jQuery(function() {
jQuery('.view-content-link').click(function() {
jQuery('#entry_page_custom_html').toggleClass('expand');
jQuery('.view-content-link').toggle();
});
});
});
</script><noscript>&amp;nbsp;</noscript> 
</div>
```

What I've gathered is

`<div class="custom-wysiwyg-text" id="fr_html_container"> </div>`

has a height of over 2000. No idea what is causing that, I set the height to 300px (which i now removed), but the view more toggle didn't show up. However if I delete the div in the console on Chrome the toggle shows up but doing so will delete the content. I do not have access to the html document that contains that element or the javascript code.

I'm lost as to what to do. If I could I'd love to just remove the view more/less altogether to get the content to display in mobile view. I tried using jQuery's remove function but it didn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div").removeClass(".view-content-links");
    $("div").removeClass(".mobile-hidden");

}
```

[image: Not Logged In]

[image: Pushed down]

[image: Logged In]

This is the test page: [Testpage](http://convio.cancer.ca/site/TR/Thirdpartyevent/IFE_ON_CommunityPartnerships_?pg=entry&fr_id=22046#.VzNe0hwpC4D)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your "see more" button?

Comment: sorry, added the view more/less div to the question

Comment: No, where on your page is the button? I don't see it on the link provided

Comment: I added pictures to show what is happening. When I'm logged in that view more button is displayed in mobile view. but that's because the `<div class="custom-wysiwyg-text" id="fr_html_container"> </div>` isn't present on the logged in page.

Comment: You do not have it in the correct `<div>` move it up a couple

Comment: that's the problem, I can't. I have no access to the html where this is all happening the most i can do is CSS and Jquery manipulation. If it were up to me I'd remove it altogether as it really isn't necessary to have it. And the CMS admins "Blackbaud" are taking their expensive sweet time removing it directly from wherever this document is. Was hoping there was another way I could remove it while I wait for them.

Comment: Well that would be a different question entirely then.

Comment: Well it was working a few days ago, something is interfering now and I have no idea what lol argh thanks for the help though i'll keep working on it

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith I just wanted to come back and thank you for the idea you gave me, I read over your comments and it not being the correct div gave me an idea, so I googled how to move elements in jQuery and found that I could use a `prependTo` function to move it out of the div it was nested in and it finally works exactly how it should! So  I don't even need to concern myself with removing the element. So thanks man.